# I want to create a linked list in "javascript"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to create a function which takes in an array and returns a linked list for example arrayToList([1,2,3]) should return

```
 list = {
value: 1,
rest: {
value: 2,
rest: {
value: 3,
rest: null
}
}
};
```

I have tried to do the following but it does not work

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
        let list = {};
        for (let i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
          let main = {};
          main.value = arr[i];
          main.rest = {};
          list.value = arr[i - 1];
          list.rest = main;
        }
        return list;
      }
```

Comment: can you describe a bit more in detail how it "does not work" ?

Comment: Hint: you can also use the "snippet" option when you edit your question to turn this javascript into an executable snippet directly in the question

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-linkedlist-javascript/ check that out

Comment: IMO, I think you forgot to save the "current state of `list`" at each iteration before "adding" something new in there. try this : `main.rest = Object.assign({}, list)` (instead of `main.rest = {}`)

Comment: `function arrayToList(list){
  if(list.length === 0) return null
  const [value, ...rest] = list;
  return { value, rest: arrayToList(rest) }
}`

Answer (score -1):

With a different perspective;

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  let bfrLst = '{';
  let t = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    bfrLst += '"value":' + arr[i] + ',"rest": ';
    if (i === arr.length - 1) {
      bfrLst += 'null';
    } else {
      bfrLst += '{';
    }
    t += '}';
  }
  return JSON.parse(bfrLst + t);
}
```